# Getting empty images from picamera module but not raspistill

Tags: camera, picamera

I wrote a python script to interface with the camera module (I have camera version 2.1). At first I tried with `picamera`, which has worked in the past. According to `pip` I have version 1.13 installed.

```
import picamera
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.sharpness = 100
camera.brightness = 50
camera.capture("/tmp/test.jpg")
```

But the image that comes out of this is blank. If I set the brightness to 100, it is a totally white image. If I set it to 50 or less, it is a black image. Everything in between is a shade of gray.

I thought the camera itself might be an issue, but when I use `raspistill` on the command line, the image comes out just fine.

**Why does `raspistill` work, when `picamera` gives an empty image?** Could it be that `picamera` needs some sort of delay and if so, how is that done?

Answer (score 1):

From the [basic recipes in the picamera docs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html) they give this example with "warm-up time"!

```py
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
sleep(2)
camera.capture('foo.jpg')
```